# Si tengo una referencia de memoria almacenada en un String puedo convertirla en su objeto original partiendo desde ese String?

Tags: java, objeto, serialización

esto es lo que esto intentando. Tengo el objeto persona y lo serializo obteniendo así su referencia de memoria, la cual almaceno en un String.

¿es posible a partir de ese String obtener el objeto Persona inicialmente?

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Persona implements Serializable {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellidos) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Persona benito = new Persona("benYto", "camelas");

        // serializar objeto a mano
        String serializadoManual = benito.getClass() + "@" + benito.hashCode();

        if (serializadoManual.equals(benito.toString())) {
            System.out.print("Serializado manual efectuado con exito");
        }

        // aplicamos ingenieria inversa. DEsserializar.
        //serializadoManual convertir una referencia de memoria almacenada en un string en su objeto orignal.
        Object object = serializadoManual;
        Persona benitoDeserializado = (Persona) object;
        // ERROR

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No podrias serializarlo asi, porque estarias combirtiendo el objeto de tipo string a objeto, lo que si podrias hacer es convertir el objeto de tipo persona a un objeto de tipo object y luego volver a convertirlo a persona:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Persona benito = new Persona("benYto", "camelas");
    Object object = benito;
    Persona benitoDeserializado = (Persona) object;
    System.out.println(benitoDeserializado.getNombre());
}
```